# Why is ctrl + o mapped to "open file" in RStudio on Mac?

Tags: macos, vim, rstudio

Both `cmd + o` and `ctrl + o` work as shortcuts for "open file" in RStudio on my MacbookPro. Isn't that strange? I'm trying to use vim mode in RStudio so I need to unmap `ctrl + o` (that's a command in vim). I tried looking in the customizing keyboard shortcuts options but couldn't find what I was looking for.

EDIT: well it turns out that `ctrl` and `cmd` are equivalent on my RStudio copy on MacbookPro. How do I remove `ctrl`'s ability to have keybinding for RStudio keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You can add `unmap <Ctrl-o> ` in ~/.vimrc

Comment: Did you try to file a bug?

Comment: @SibiCoder but I want to use ```Ctrl-o``` in vim

Comment: You can first unmap it so that its mapping goes off. And then, you can map it again.

Answer (score 0):

This has bugged me for a while as well, but I just discovered that the Vim bindings (for ctrl + o for example) start working when you turn off the RStudio default keyboard shortcuts. So, for example, go to Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts..., and then type "open" into the filter text box, double-click the Shortcut cell in the "Open File..." row, delete the contents, press enter, and finally click apply.

This applies to RStudio version: 1.0.136.